# SSH security breach, or authentication issues, have I been hacked?

Tags: ssh, osx-lion

I am using a MBPro (just received) and am continually seeing a corruption with remote access, unhindered, resulting in a missing Operating System (as per Applications, in System Profiler- No information found).

I see "sh" and "sntp" open quickly and close via Activity Monitor. I tried typing "shutdown -k now" and the reply is "Wall: can't open temporary file: Read only file system
                       System shutdown has arrived
                       but you'll have to do it yourself"

After less than 1 hr with a brand new laptop, with set-up assitance from Apple, I'm running a virtual system, and have no Applications listed in System Profiler. I lost my super user status, and am slowly losing all administrative authority.

I don't understand what's going on. "logind" is listed, on startup, in Activity Monitor, and when I try to use my firewall it's ineffective, whether using "Block all incoming connections" or the custom option adding specific Applications.

I would like to configure my ipfw, but I'm getting an error msg-" file or folder does not exist, in Terminal.

In single user mode, there are all kinds of disconcerting entries, about a memory leak, acpi disabled?? acpi enabled, got boot device-long file path-that includes Block storge device, bsd root: disk0s2, major 14, minor 2 com.apple.launchd 1 with an unkown ip address 5.1XX.98.75. MACx_swapon Success.

Is there a ssh,telnet, or remote access security compromise? I use my box for streaming radio, tight email control, and off line DVD/CD enjoyment. That's it no file storage. The only thing I have downloaded is Flash Player from adobe, with Apple's help- strange I thought. I use no perirpherals, other than a logitech mouse.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you unplug this computer from the internet and restart does the unwanted behavior continue?

Comment: If this is a brand-new MacBook Pro that Apple set up for you, take it back to Apple and have them look at it.  It could be that they made a mistake and left some tool installed that they were supposed to remove, or it could be that they imported malware from your previous Mac.